# Why put type_of_element#id in CSS?

Tags: css

Why would you want to do:

```
h1#chapter1 { text-align: center }
```

Instead of

```
#chapter1 { text-align: center }
```

If an id is supposed to be unique in a document tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do that to let the next developer know what element the ID is on.

I do not do that on divs, sections, or any "containers".

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is done to make it easy to tell exactly what sort of element has the ID without having to leave the stylesheet.  I think would also have a higher specificity than just #element, so you could override a standard #element selector with div#element.

Answer (score 0):

Strange question, perhaps you have the same id on different elements across different pages that share the same stylesheet?

E.g. on home.html you have `<h1 id="title">`

on about.html you have `<h2 id="title">`

But they both use same stylesheet and you want to apply a style for the homepage title only..

Also it wouldnt make sense to make the CSS syntax inconsistent across different kind of selectors. Would cause more confusion then it was worth.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the same ID for two different elements across different pages

Comment: Just one possible reason why you might need to do it :), remember people dont always have access to change the markup in big projects